# How to use less in a script without getting ESC escape characters?

Tags: scripting, less, escape-characters

When I use `less` at the command line the output is like
[image]

but when I use `less` from within a bash script I get:
[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]

How can I use `less` in a bash script and not get all the escape characters and have it work like it does at the interactive command line?

Comment: You have an environment variable whose name begins with `LESS` set to some value in your interactive shell, but not in your shell script.  Do `printenv | grep LESS` to find out its identity, and then you can set it in your shell script too, or use the equivalent command-line options.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `-R` flag:

> -r or --raw-control-chars
>
> Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  The default is to
>   display control characters using the caret notation; for example, a
>   control-A (octal 001) is displayed as "^A".  Warning: when the -r
>   option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual appearance of the
>   screen (since this depends  on  how  the  screen responds to each type
>   of control character).  Thus, various display problems may result,
>   such as long lines being split in the wrong place.
>
> -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
>
> Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw"
>   form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in
>   most cases.  ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the form:
>
> ```
>            ESC [ ... m
> ```
>
> where the "..." is zero or more color specification characters For the
>   purpose of keeping track of screen appearance, ANSI color escape
>   sequences are assumed to not  move  the  cursor.   You can make less
>   think that characters other than "m" can end ANSI color escape
>   sequences by setting the environment variable LESSANSIENDCHARS to the
>   list of characters which can end a color escape sequence.  And you can
>   make less think that characters other than the standard ones may
>   appear between the ESC and the m by setting the environment variable
>   LESSANSIMIDCHARS to the list of characters which can appear.

From `less` man page.